# Asp.net core 2.2 variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT not working on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I am trying to find out what the problem is with my application but I always get the following error page:

[image]

I tried adding to azure the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable, and then restarted, but it still does not work. Am I missing smth?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested at my side, and the app environment was changed to development:

[image]

Then, for testing, I just throw a Exception in my code, and I will see the detailed error page:

[image]

So, I have some suggestions:

### 1. Check if you have saved the application settings on Azure portal. And restart the web app.

### 2. You can force to use development environment in startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //if (env.IsDevelopment())
    //{
    //  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //}

    // Force to use development environment
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    ...
}
```

And then re-publish it to you web app.

### 3. You can use remote debugging. Here is a tutorial: [Troubleshoot an app in Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio)